# Framed Links are Ribbon Graphs

Tags: mathematical-physics, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am reading [this paper](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/%7Eptingley/lecturenotes/Kauffman_vs_sl2.pdf).<sup>1</sup> Near the middle of page 2 the author seems to state that a framed link is just a ribbon graph.  Is that an accurate statement?

<sup>1</sup>Peter Tingley: A minus sign that used to annoy me but now I know why it is there (notes on the Jones polynomial).

Comment: The comment states that a framed link is equivalent to a link tied in a flat ribbon. A link tied in a flat ribbon is not the same thing as a ribbon graph. Is that the comment you were referring to?

Comment: @AdamLowrance Yes thanks.  So now I need to figure out how ribbon graphs differ from links tied in a flat ribbon.  I'll get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is nearly accurate.  A ribbon graph is usually an inclusion $\Gamma\to\Sigma$ that is a homotopy equivalence between a graph $\Gamma$ and an oriented surface $\Sigma$ with boundary (one of the many ways to define a *combinatorial map*).  A ribbon graph embedded in $S^3$ is called various things, such as a *spatial graph* or a *spatial ribbon graph*, diagrams for which have been called *flat vertex graphs up to regular isotopy*.  A framed link is such a spatial graph where every vertex is degree-$2$, modulo edge subdivision.  The correspondence is that the surface $\Sigma$ gives a section of the normal bundle of the embedding of $\Gamma$ in $S^3$.

The $\mathcal{RIBBON}$ category later in the paper is a category of framed tangles.  Or, the category of oriented spatial graphs such that interior vertices are all degree-$2$, modulo edge subdivision.

If it were just of ribbon graphs, then there'd be no concept of over- vs. under-crossings, just permutations.